# C program to find the second largest element (also the largest)

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop, if-statement

This is the code I wrote and I'm wondering if there is any solution for the way I am thinking(the second number should be < largest and also bigger than the previous number). Thanks and sorry for [duplicate] but I am really curious if there is anything similar.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() 
{
    int arr[10];
    int i;
    int greatest;
    int second;

    printf("Enter 10 values:");

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        scanf("\n%d", &arr[i]);
    }

    greatest = arr[0];

    for (i = 1; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (greatest < arr[i])
        {
            greatest = arr[i];
        }
    }

    second = arr[i];
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] < greatest && second > arr[i - 1])
        {
            second = arr[i];
        }
    }

    printf("The greatest number is : %d", greatest);
    printf("\nThe second greatest number is: %d", second);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you know how to find the largest?  The second largest works the same way, except that you also check the largest against your candidate.  You should only need one loop.

Comment: `second  = arr[i];` accesses `arr` out of bounds, at this point `i==10`. And `arr[i - 1]` is out of bounds for `i==0`, altho that may not necessarily get executed

Comment: @Benz91 Benz What does >be bigger than the previous number" mean?

Comment: `scanf("\n%d",&arr[i]);` is no different than `scanf("%d",&arr[i]);`. There's only one case (that I know of) where `\n` is useful in a format string, and that's when you're reading a string with a scan set, e.g. `char s[100]; scanf("%[^\n]", s);`

Answer (score -3, accepted):

this should work.

```
if(arr[1] > arr[0]){
    greatest = arr[1];
    second = arr[0];
}else{
    greatest = arr[0];
    second = arr[1];
}

for(int i=2;i<10;i++)
{
    if(second < arr[i]){
        if(greatest < arr[i]){
            second = greatest;
            greatest = arr[i];
        }
        else{
            second = arr[i];
        }
    }
}
```

First I fill `greatest` and `second` with the first two entries of the array in the correct order.

Then I run, in a for-loop, from the 3rd (as i already sorted the first 2) to the 10th value and check for each entry:

- if the value is greater than `second` and also greater than
  `greatest` then this value is now the greatest value. thus the current
  greatest value is now the 2nd greatest value.
- if the value is greater than `second` and smaller than `greatest` then
  this value is the 2nd greatest value. and the greatest value remains.
- if the value is smaller than `second` it is neither the greatest nor
  the 2nd greatest value.

Comment: Why does it work? Elaboration would greatly improve this answer.

Comment: [doesn't work for `int arr[] = {1,1,1,2,2,2};`](https://godbolt.org/z/qY1735bYe)

Comment: it works for `int arr[] = {1,1,1,2,2,2}; `. you would get for second and greatest each "2", which is true, because the two largest entries in the array are each "2". If you want the two largest values to be different, then my solution would not work.

Answer (score 0):

### The solution

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n = 5;
    int arr[n] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int largest = INT_MIN, second = INT_MIN;

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if(arr[i] > largest)
        {
            second = largest;
            largest = arr[i];
        }
        else if(arr[i] > second && arr[i] != largest)
        {
            second = arr[i];
        }
    }

    printf("Largest: %d\nSecond: %d\n", largest, second);
}
```

Okay so here is the trick

When iterating through the array you have three cases.

The first case is that you have found a number greater than the largest number you have kept.

We attempt to initially keep the largest number at a minimum, hence the INT_MIN, so that any initial number that the array has will be within our scope. If we assume the initial largest number to be 0 then negative values wouldn't be considered at all and the program would fail if the array consisted of all negative numbers (an array with only 1 positive number would also fail since we also want the second largest).

If a greater number than the `largest` value is detected, we assign the `largest` value as the detected value. Since the former largest number is now the second-largest value we assign `second` to be `largest`. Hence

```
second = largest;
largest = arr[i];
```

The second case is that we have encountered a number that is not greater than the largest number that we currently hold but is greater than the second. Then we assign `second` to the said value hence:

```
second = arr[i];
```

The third case is that we have encountered a value that is neither larger than the larger nor larger than the second. We ignore the number if that is the case.

### What is wrong with your code

The part that deals with the greatest number looks correct. However, the way that you set `second` to be `arr[i]` is wrong since `i` would be 10 here and `arr[i]` would be out of the bounds of the array. Also, you are iterating from 0 to 10 and checking `arr[i-1]` which is clearly unsafe.

Comment: It is a bad code. For example the user can enter all negative values.

Comment: Fixed with INT_MIN, I think.

Comment: Logic error: A value which is largest early in the loop can never become second.  Your own test case is a good example: the `else` clause is never executed

Comment: Disregard my (now deleted) comment.  It was misleading.

Comment: @Peter you are right indeed will fix in a second

Comment: @Peter fixed now?

Comment: An answer should not be "maybe this will work." If you don't know that it works, you have a suggestion or comment at best, but not an answer.

Comment: @Chris well this does work

Comment: _Why_ does it work? Elaboration makes for good answers.

Comment: @Chris would the explanation suffice?

Comment: Better certainly, but would be aided by addressing where the OP went wrong, so they can not only solve this problem but avoid making the same mistakes again.

Comment: [doesn't work for `int arr[] = {1,1,1,2,2,2};`](https://godbolt.org/z/Pb9ovdrf1)

Comment: Özgür Güzeldereli, note than when an array element is not in the top 2 (a common occurrence), this approach takes 2 compares. [da-Kai](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72916068/2410359) takes one.

Comment: @yano fixed, forgot to check duplicates

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I am not sure that this comment is relevant.

Comment: @Chris also added why the OP's code is wrong

Comment: looks good for all the test cases I can dream up. Recommend adding the need to `#include <limits.h>`, where `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX` live.

Comment: @yano done. (filler)

Answer (score 0):

Your key mistake would be here:

> ```
>    for (i = 1; i < 10; i++)
>    {
>        if (greatest < arr[i])
>        {
>            greatest = arr[i];
>        }
>    }
>
>    second = arr[i];
> ```

Your loop conditions means that when the loops ends, `i` must be `10`. That means `arr[i]` is out of bounds. This invokes undefined behavior. We have no way of knowing what the value of `second` is going into the next loop, and this will potentially affect your results.

You likely meant: `second = arr[0]` to initialize `second` with the first element in `arr`.

Having initialized `second` properly, you'd want to change that value only if the current element in the list is greater than the existing value for `second` *and* smaller than `greatest`.

In your code you've compared `second` to `arr[i - 1]`. When `i` is `0` on the first iteration, this will give you a negative index.

```
second = arr[0];

for (size_t i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    if (arr[i] < greatest && arr[i] > second) {
        second = arr[i];
    }
}
```

As a general suggestion, you do not need to declare your variables all at the beginning of the function in modern C. Declare them closer to actual use. Additionally, your `i` variables do not convey useful information beyond the scope of the loops, so scope them to the loops. That would have helped you catch the first out of bounds array access.